# Ajax call get json data dynamically from elements ID

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am calling an AJAX request with the below and I need to obtain the JSON data dynamically.

I tried by getting the ID of each `h1` element, using `var id = $(this).attr("id");` and then using `data.id` inside the success but it returns undefined because I think its trying to get the value of `id` which doesn't exist.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
var interval = 1000;
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/admin/wallboard/?action=stats',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('h1').each(function(index, element) {
                if($(this).attr("id")) {
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
                    console.log( data.id );
                    //$('#' + $(this).attr("id")).text( data.id );
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("error");
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            console.log("complete");
            // Schedule the next
            //setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
        }
});
setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
```

Sample JSON data:

```
{"avg_ticket":"No responses yet","datetime":"16-12-2018 15:13:46","phone_regs":"83 \/ 111"}
```

Comment: Can you add sample JSON for "data" which is returned in success.

Comment: sure, check my update

Comment: Your json has avg_ticket, datetime, phone_regs. There is no id.

Comment: correct, thats the issue. i'm using `var id = $(this).attr("id");` and i want to get `data.avg_ticket`, `data.datetime` based on `var id` as i put above

Comment: There has to be id in JSON else how will you match which data to pick in case of multiple record

Comment: i'm not sure if you read the post, i'm looping through each `h1` element which has an ID and the data in the JSON is from the elements ID

Comment: please put your html code here, that you trying to read though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a solution by using `data[id]` instead of `data.id`

`id` is dynamic based on the ID attribute of each `h1` element